# Hiding a Facebook ID from the page's source

Tags: facebook, profile, image

I know the title might not be very explicit, but here's my problem:
All of the users on my website are connected via Facebook. And since their facebook picture is displayed on their profile, anybody can view the page's source and find their Facebook ID (I am using `https://graph.facebook.com/*Facebook id*/picture` as a source for the picture). Should I be concerned about this? Is there any way to "hide" this information to the visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://graph.facebook.com/*Facebook id*/picture` will translate to an Akamai link which still contains the Facebook id. You can try saving all the photos... but that's not really worth it and you will have to re-save to keep up with the latest version of `https://graph.facebook.com/*Facebook id*/picture`

Even then, since a user's main profile picture is publicly available, it will likely be cached  by Google so one can do a Google Image search against the picture you tried to obfuscate.

So no, there is no way to hide this information

Comment: And you don't even need to be concerned about this public id, as it is not mission critical and public anyways